# Python combine (Concatenate) data from multiple rows in CSV into one cell in another CSV

Tags: python, sorting, csv, ip, concatenation

I am running some nmap scan reports daily that I am trying to fully automate with Python. I have a CSV with IP and a port number, one per line. I'm trying to consolidate the port numbers as a list. Below is an example of the input csv:

```
    address       port
    192.168.3.5   80
    192.168.3.5   443
    192.168.3.5   3389
    192.168.3.5   137
    192.168.4.77  80
    192.168.4.77  445
```

The output should look like this:

```
    address         ports
    192.168.3.5     80, 443, 3389, 137
    192.168.4.77    80,445
```

Here is a the whole script:

```
import subprocess

# Function to run peepingtom
def run_peepingtom(dir):

    scanfile = dir + '/nmap-scan.xml'

    subprocess.call(["python", "peepingtom/peepingtom.py", "-x", scanfile, "-o", dir + "/peepcaptures/"])


# Function to run NMAP on a list of IPs. The scan results will be in "dir" location
def run_nmap(dir):

    targets = dir + '/targets.txt'

    subprocess.call(["nmap", "-vv", "-A", "-sV", "-Pn", "-T4", "-iL", targets, "-oA", dir + "/nmap-scan"])

    # Create an HTML report
    subprocess.call(["xsltproc", dir + "/nmap-scan.xml", "-o", dir + "/nmap-scan.html"])


# Function to convert NMAP output to CSV
def run_nmap_parser(dir):

    scanfile = dir + '/nmap-scan.xml'

    subprocess.call(["python", "nmap-parser-xml-to-csv/nmap-parser-xml-to-csv.py", scanfile, "-s", ",", "-o", dir + "/nmap-scan.csv"])


def main():

    outputdir= '2015-07-20'

    run_nmap(outputdir)

    run_peepingtom(outputdir)

    run_nmap_parser(outputdir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wrote a Python script to do the scans and creates CSV outputs, etc. I used few open source tools to get what I need. I need to do more manual formatting after, which is what I am trying to automate. My skills with Python are pretty limited so any help is appreciated, where to start?

Comment: 1. Please mention as to what is the problem you are facing with the code that you have written. 2. Provide a [MCVE] of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script would be able to process your input CSV file. It reads each line of your CSV report log in and for each IP address adds it to a dictionary. Each dictionary entry holds a `set` of the ports being used for the given IP address. The output is sorted by IP address.

```
import csv, collections, socket

d_ip = collections.defaultdict(set)

with open("report_log.csv", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    headers = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        d_ip[row[0]].add(row[1])
        #d_ip[row[0]].append(row[1])   # if a list is preferred

with open("port_usage.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(headers)
    print "%-20s %s" % (headers[0], headers[1])

    # Sort by IP address
    ip_sorted = d_ip.keys()
    ip_sorted.sort(key=lambda x: socket.inet_aton(x))

    for ip in ip_sorted:
        l_ports = list(d_ip[ip])
        l_ports.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
        csv_output.writerow([ip, ", ".join(l_ports)])
        print "%-20s %s" % (ip, ", ".join(l_ports))
```

Which would print the following output:

```
address              port
192.168.3.5          80, 137, 443, 3389
192.168.4.77         80, 445
```

If all ports (not just the unique ones) are needed, simply change to `defaultdict(list)`, change `.add()` to `.append()` and comment out the `sort`.

Comment: That works pretty good Martin! There are duplicates though,  I think the CSV should be sorted by IP first to make sure those are consecutive .

Comment: I have updated the script to now sort the output by IP address.

Comment: This is probably a separate question but can this be appended to another CSV by matching the IP?  I have a separate spreadsheet that has IP, OS, POC, and other fields. It would be great if I can append the "Open ports" list to that file. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: It is probably best to start a new question. Give example input csv entries and the expected output. You need to have a stab at some code too to get you going.